# Unable to read from XML file in a SharePoint Timer Job

Tags: xml, sharepoint, timer-jobs

I have a custom timer job which should read some data from an XML file and save it in a word file. I tested this code in a simple web part and it works perfectly fine. However it is not working with custom timer job. Here is the code -

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        #if (DEBUG)
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Assert(false);
        #endif


        // get a reference to the current site collection's content database
        SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[targetInstanceId];


        //Define a string builder object
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        //double revenue = 0;
        //creating object of configuration class

        //Reading page size from xml configuration file
        int intPageLimit = weeklyConfig.readPageSize();
        //Reading column name from xml configuration file
        List<string> strList = weeklyConfig.readColumnName();
        //Reading list name from xml configuration file
        string strListName = weeklyConfig.readListName();
        //Reading Library name from xml 
        string strLibraryName = weeklyConfig.readLibraryName();
        stringBuilder.Append(intPageLimit);
        foreach (string str in strList)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(str);
        }
        stringBuilder.Append(strListName);
        stringBuilder.Append(strLibraryName);
        SPFolder customerDocLib = null;
        customerDocLib = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Folders["Reports"];
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        string fileName = "TestReport_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss") + ".doc";//Creating .doc file
        customerDocLib.Files.Add(fileName, stream);//writing memory stream to doc file and saving it into SharePoint document library
    }
```

Here is the code which creates the XML file. I have added this code in an Event Receiver at feature level. I'm saving this XML file in inetpub's virtual directory where my site collection is deployed. Path - C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/38118/Configuration/ConfigFile.xml

```
public static void CreateConfigFile(String path)
    {
        //Use an xml Writer
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path + "/ConfigFile.xml"))
        {
            //Start the Xml Document
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            //Create Root element
            writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
            //Write Element in the root element
            writer.WriteElementString("PageSize", "33");
            writer.WriteElementString("Column", "Title");
            writer.WriteElementString("Column", "SalesPerson");
            writer.WriteElementString("Column", "SalesTarget");
            writer.WriteElementString("Column", "Achieved");
            writer.WriteElementString("Column", "UnitPrice");
            writer.WriteElementString("Column", "TotalRevenue");
            writer.WriteElementString("ListName", "SalesList");
            writer.WriteElementString("LibraryName", "Reports");
            //End the root element
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            //End the Xml Document
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }



    }
```

These are the methods I'm using to read from the XML file. These work totally fine with a webpart. But it gives an exception "Object reference not set for an instance of an object" when used in a timer job.

```
public class configuration : LayoutsPageBase
{
   public List<string> readColumnName()
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("~/AutomatedReport/ConfigFile.xml"));
        List<string> listColumnName = new List<string>();
        string element = "";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                element = reader.Name;
            }

            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                switch (element)
                {
                    case "Column": listColumnName.Add(reader.Value.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return listColumnName;
    }
```

This is only one of the methods I'm using to read. This is reading the column names of a  list.

The XML file is generated properly. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your XML file in 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14
directory.....
Mostly OWSTimer don't have an access to
Server.MapPath("~/AutomatedReport/ConfigFile.xml")

Comment: One important thing Prashant was missing is the different context of execution: w3wp.exe in the web part and owstimer.exe in the timer job.

Comment: Another risk or that configuration storage option is that if more servers are added to the farm, some will not be synced to the latest version and some won't have the file at all unless all changes are explicitly synched every time!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://spg.codeplex.com for better configuration storage options.